# How to use Custom PHP Functions in eZ Publish Templates?

Tags: php, ezpublish

Hi 
i am wondering if i could use PHP functions in ez publish templating. If any one knows how to use it. Any hint will be greatful.

eg:- i want to use str_replace() PHP function in ez-publish template.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly we have to make an extension to use PHP function in ez publish.

Steps for making an extension in ezpublish is given in link below:

http://blog.developeronhire.com/using-custom-php-functions-in-ez-publish-templates/

Hope it will solve your porblem.

Answer (score 0):

See these two doc items...
For replacing elements of an Array
http://doc.ez.no/eZ-Publish/Technical-manual/4.x/Reference/Template-operators/Arrays/replace

For replacing in a string... 
http://doc.ez.no/eZ-Publish/Technical-manual/4.x/Reference/Template-operators/Strings/replace